# iOS: UIVIew touches delegates vs single tap recognizer

Tags: ios, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

I am handling `Touches` delegates and `UITapGestureRecognizer` for single tap. Following are the methods. When I single tap on my View, I get three events in order of `TouchesBegan`, `SingleTap`, and `TouchesEnded`. Is there anyway to stop `TouchesEnded` event when I have `SingleTap` detected? Basicaaly I don't want to perform tasks in `TouchesEnded` if `TouchesMoved` didn't happen. I have done this using failTouchEnded BOOL variable in `SingleTap` and checking it in TouchesEnded but not sure if it is a good idea!

```
   - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    }

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
          failTouchEnded = NO;
    }

    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
          if(failTouchEnded) return;

    }

    - (void)GestureView:(GestureView*)view handleSignleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
          failTouchEnded = YES;
    }
```

Comment: Your idea it's right... I always use it to solve similar problem !

Comment: Great! I was wondering there might be something similar requireGestureRecognizerToFail method!

Answer (score 0):

gestureRecognizer has a property cancelsTouchesInView. if it is YES (which is default) cancels the touches if the gesture recognizer recognizes the gesture. So you will get a touches canceled instead of touches ended. You should set delaysTouchesEnded to YES too if it is not YES